# How do private feeds get transferred between two different portals?

Tags: web-service

I have some doubts about how the RSS private feeds, get transferred between one portal to another.

The whole point is to allow private RSS feeds to be consumed by external clients, and in 99% of cases, they support basic authentication and SSL. The problem is that external clients can't use FORM authentication of the portal to reach the private pages, making existing private RSS feeds all but useless.

Is there anyway this problem can be resolved, or is it already resolved I need to know.This will help me in a project that I started working on,I want a service that will enable two separate bloggers to share their private posts with each other without necessarily requiring a user name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use some kind of tokenning system, if a blogger want to share his RSS feed with another blogger he just has to give the token to the other user, or even better generate a unique token for each reader.

Something like :

http://www.website.com/flux.rss?key=549424e1778e55c0dbfb8bd4a2f6877330b9a46b

Answer (score 1):

Its a know problem that many RSS readers don't handle authentication correctly. The best option is to use a token (key) system like Techbrunch suggests. If you want to keep the tokens private then force SSL with a redirect on port 80.